# How to fix "ERROR: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found"?

Tags: android, android-studio

I created and deleted some activities and this error happened.

Error show:

> "ERROR: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF059.png)

Here is my Build.Gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.application12"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:11.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Share you gradle files.

Comment: edited first post

Comment: share code of your build.gradle file

Comment: Make sure your project level build.gradle have classpath.

Comment: share also the build.gradle in the root folder

Comment: Try to disable then enable Android plugin.